# Using tuples in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am a beginner in pig and trying to understand tuple data type, I have a file as below :

```
       cat student.csv
id,name,grade,contact_details 
s1234,Mohan,8,(Delhi,9811830)
s2345,Nisha,10,(Delhi,257891)
s3456,Anuj,12,(Delhi,9897212)
s4567,vishal,14,(Delhi,989175)
```

Where contact details is a tuple consisting of city and phone :

I have loaded it in a relation as below :

```
    student = load 'student.csv' using PigStorage(',') as
 (id:chararray,
  name:chararray,
  grade:int,
  contact: tuple(city:chararray,phone:chararray));
```

Now when i try to dump the result I am not getting my tuple in the output, below is the output of dump_student :

```
grunt> dump student; 
(s1234,Mukul,8,)
(s2345,Nikita,10,)
(s3456,Anuj,12,)
(s4567,vishu,14,)
grunt> 

grunt> describe student;
student: {id: chararray,name: chararray,grade: int,contact: (city: chararray,phone: chararray)}
```

am i missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

The delimiter ',' you are using is causing the file to be loaded incorrectly,since ',' is also present in the tuple.Either replace the ',' between the fields except within the tuple or just load the fields into 5 fields and replace '(' and ')' and concat to get contact_details from city and phone fields.

Option 1:With ' ' as delimiter

```
id name grade contact_details 

s1234 Mohan 8 (Delhi,9811830)
s2345 Nisha 10 (Delhi,257891)
s3456 Anuj 12 (Delhi,9897212)
s4567 vishal 14 (Delhi,989175)

student = load 'student.csv' using PigStorage(' ') as (id:chararray, name:chararray,  grade:int,  contact: tuple(city:chararray,phone:chararray));
```

Option 2: With ',' as delimiter

```
id,name,grade,contact_details 

s1234,Mohan,8,(Delhi,9811830)
s2345,Nisha,10,(Delhi,257891)
s3456,Anuj,12,(Delhi,9897212)
s4567,vishal,14,(Delhi,989175)


student = load 'student.csv' using PigStorage(',') as (id:chararray, name:chararray,  grade:int,  city:chararray,phone:chararray);
student_new = FOREACH A GENERATE id,name,grade,CONCAT(REPLACE(CONCAT(city,' '),'(',''),REPLACE(phone,')','')) AS contact_details;
```